# Subtract independent variable from target in linear regression

Tags: regression

I have a simple linear regression problem where:

$y = a*x_1 + b*x_2 + c$

In my problem my target variable is more conveniently defined as:

$y - x_1 = b'*x_2 + c'$

I still get the same coefficients for $x_2$ and the intercept as well as the same $R^2$ and mean squared error. Is this expected?

Generally, is such a transformation of the target/response variable beneficial? e.g. if I get a more normally distributed target variable?

Comment: If you get all the same statistics in the two models, then necessarily your estimated value of $a$ must have been $1$.  If that's not true, then please double-check your results.

Comment: (..and it is extremely unlikely to have been exactly equal to one, so definitely, check your results.)

Comment: If you have not yet considered a surface fit of the form "z = f(x, y)" post the data (or a link to the data) and I can make a 3D scatter plot with an example 3D fitted surface and contour plot.